# self.class.name in a mix-in module

Tags: ruby

I have a module with methods that write to a log. Into each message I want to put the name of the class that logged this message.

The module can be mixed in using `include` or `extend`. I need my log to have correct class names in each case.

Distilled code:

```
module M
  def f
    self.class.name
  end
end

class C
  extend M
  include M
end

p C.f # => "Class"
p C.new.f # => "C"
```

As you see, the first call incorrectly prints `"Class"`. I want it to be `"C"` as well.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to resort to hooks, simply change your behavior when `self` is a `Class`/`Module`:

```
module M
  def f
    self.is_a?(Module) ? name : self.class.name
  end
end

class C
  extend M
  include M
end

C.f     #=> "C"
C.new.f #=> "C"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, don't know if a better method exists.

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def f
    self.class.name
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def f
      self.name
    end
  end
end

class C
  include M
end
```

Comment: You don't have to extend. The methods that you want to turn into class methods you put inside the ClassMethods module. :)

Comment: What if I just want to extend, and not include? Then I have to do `extend M::ClassMethods` for no good reason. Personally, I also just really dislike the whole extending-upon-inclusion pattern.